# Ubuntu does not put Fedora into GRUB menu

Tags: 12.04, grub2, window, fedora

I have installed a number of operating systems, including Fedora. Most recently I installed Ubuntu, and Ubuntu installed its own version of the GRUB bootloader. However, Fedora does not show up on the list of operating systems to boot from.

How can I get Fedora back in my  boot menu?

Answer (score 10):

Mount the other partition, and then run `sudo update-grub`.

To do that, open nautilus, and then right click the drive like shown below and click "Mount":

[image]

After that, run `sudo update-grub` in a terminal.

Fedora should show up. Now when you reboot, you can select it.

Comment: just curious, why would grub not find the unmounted partition?  is this a bug related to Fedora/other non Ubuntu Linux flavors? I've dual boot 2 versions of Ubuntu and not had to mount the other partition to get grub to find it...BTW I'm not criticizing your post, seem logical to me, I was just wondering why the workaround was necessary

Comment: @TrailRider I removed ubuntu 12.10 and installed Linux Mint 13 incase there is bug in ubuntu, I got the same result i.e. fedora missing from boot menu.

Comment: @TrailRider I've no clue. Fedora recognizes Ubuntu fine, Ubuntu recognized my Debian install fine, it just doesn't like Fedora. *shrug*

Comment: I think ubuntu can't mount lvm partition by default.
`sudo apt-get install lvm2`
so, you can mount fedora boot partition and update grub.

Comment: Mounting Fedora partitions doesn't work for Ubuntu 23 and Fedora 38, and I think it doesn't work for many other versions.

Answer (score 2):

The OP asked "How can I get Fedora back in my boot menu?"; at least one answer was provided that resolved the same issue that I had with Ubuntu & Fedora boot menus. Might wanna mark it as "Solved"?

Here's another link to the Fedora forums where the same problem was resolved by an answer that was posted here, and the thread was consequently marked as "Solved":

[Grub (Ubuntu) does not detect Fedora 17](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=279221)

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bug in 12.10....

Can you boot in to Ubuntu 12.04, then run boot repair or use the following commands to see if you get access to Fedora from grub?

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
sudo update-grub
```

Replacing sdX with the actual drive, which will probably be sda, but use disk utility to double check if you are unsure.

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* an answer to the OP question, but nonetheless a good enough workaround for the same problem.
With Ubuntu 23.04 and Fedora 38, I was able to add an Ubuntu menu entry to fedora's grub using:

> sudo os-prober #(detected windows and ubuntu)
>
> sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg #(configured fedora's
> grub)

Having installed Ubuntu latest, I changed the boot order from bios, putting Fedora as first so to load Fedora's grub at startup.