# Managing Grub in case of 2 linux installations

Tags: grub2

I installed Ubuntu 12.04. My default windows bootloader is taken over by Ubuntu. After this, I installed Fedora 16 and then my bootloader was taken over by Fedora. So, now I see Fedora Grub Menu when I start my laptop. Is there any way that I can get back the Ubuntu 12.04 Grub menu without messing up anything?

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar question recently, see the link below :

[Ubuntu hides Fedora in grub Menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171947/ubuntu-hides-fedora-in-grub-menu/171950#171950)

Have a look at both answers and you should resolve the problem, although my answer was as below, the other answer & comments will help too :

Can you boot in to Ubuntu 12.04, then run boot repair or use the following commands to see if you get access to Fedora from grub?

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
sudo update-grub
```

Replacing sdX with the actual drive, which will probably be sda, but use disk utility to double check if you are unsure.

Comment: Thank for letting me know, glad to help. Please accept our answer or upvote it, to let others know it helped. :o)