# Ubuntu Messed up my Grub

Tags: fedora, boot, grub2, raid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu does not put Fedora into GRUB menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171947/ubuntu-does-not-put-fedora-into-grub-menu)

I have Windows XP Installed, and i have installed Fedora 15, yesterday. Updated it today to 17, and installed Ubuntu. After installing ubuntu, it messed up the grub. `Grub` wont find fedora anymore. I have tried booting from the Live CD, and installing `Boot-Repair`. It find a `Raid` unit, asks for `mdadm`. Tried with `mdadm`, and withoud `dmraid`. No progress. When i go to my files, in the live cd, the fedora unit shows up. What have i done wrong? haha
I think, it's something about this raid unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the `os-prober` package is installed in Ubuntu with `dpkg -l os-prober`.

If it isn't installed, then:

```
sudo apt-get install os-prober
sudo update-grub
```

BTW, Ubuntu 12.04 does some horrible things to the grub menu with `/etc/default/grub`.  You might want to edit it to comment out these lines:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

and add these in their place:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
```

This will stop the grub menu from being hidden at boot and will make whatever you choose from the menu be the next default.  It also allows `grub-set-default` and `grub-reboot` to work (they don't when GRUB_DEFAULT is hard-coded to 0).

Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` after editing it, and then `sudo grub-set-default 0` to make sure it has a sane default.

Also, if you don't like the submenu that it hides old kernels with, then patch `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` like this:

```
--- 10_linux.orig       2012-05-17 07:07:17.000000000 +0000
+++ 10_linux    2012-08-27 03:46:54.803088897 +0000
@@ -254,12 +254,12 @@

   list=`echo $list | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -vx $linux | tr '\n' ' '`

-  if [ "$list" ] && ! $in_submenu; then
-    echo "submenu \"Previous Linux versions\" {"
-    in_submenu=:
-  fi
 done

-if $in_submenu; then
-  echo "}"
-fi
```

and, again, run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: I already have os-prober instlled. I've made everything you told me, and another thing i read in a forum. I've added this:

    #!/bin/sh
    cat << \EOF
    menuentry "Fedora" {
        set root=(hd0,3)
        chainloader +1
    }
    EOF

to `/etc/grub.d/17_fedora` and now, it shows up on grub. My fedora partition is on `/dev/sda3`, as `lmv2` file system.

Comment: All i get in the grub menu, is ` error: invalid signature` I have read somewhere, that Grub don`t allow you to add fedora to its menus, because of the Raid partition, and what must be done, is linking Grub with the fedora default's grub. Can someone please help me? :P

Comment: grub's disk and partition numbering is zero-based, so (hd0,3) refers to /dev/sda4, not /dev/sda3.  Try `(hd0,2)` instead.

Comment: Nope, it still shows: error: invalid signature

Comment: before restarting, i updated grub

Comment: Is the grub boot loader installed on /dev/sda3?  try `file -s /dev/sda3` - if the output mentions a filesystem rather than a grub or an `x86 boot sector` then it isn't installed. If grub isnt installed on /dev/sda3, you have two choices: 1. chroot into your fedora partition from a rescue CD and run `grub-install /dev/sda3`, or 2. edit your /etc/grub.d/17_fedora to specify the exact filenames (relative to /dev/sda3 as root dir) of the kernel and initrd.  I would have thought that os-prober would do that - you don't have `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` in your /etc/default/grub, do you?

Comment: I just found this: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=685159 - known bug in recent versions os-prober.  A workaround to get os-prober to recognise fedora is to mount the fedora partition in ubuntu first, and then run update-grub.  e.g. (as root) `mkdir /fedora ; mount /dev/sda3 /fedora`. since your fedora partition is lvm2, it'll be a little more complicated than that - i.e. install lvm2 on ubuntu and configured it.

Comment: I figured it out yesterday. Installed lmv2, (i wasn't able to mount without it). After mounting, i updated grub again, and it worked. Thank you.