# Problem with triple boot!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, lvm, fedora

I have installed Windows 10 , Ubuntu 14.04 and Fedora 22 on my system in that order. Fedora is using LVM so it is not accessible in Nautilus(Ubuntu). That is my first problem. The second problem is that Fedora installed its own GRUB, which had all the correct boot entries for all three OS. but when i updated Ubuntu it also updated GRUB and reset the GRUB installed by Fedora and now only Ubuntu and Win 10 is available in the boot menu of GRUB. Can someone please tell me how to fix this. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into similar situation like  6 or 7 years ago, not remember well, but will try to help.

First you need to mount LVM partition; (ref: [linuxquestion](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/fedora-35/how-can-i-mount-lvm-partition-in-ubuntu-569507/))

> 1- Boot Ubuntu.
>
> 2- Install lvm2:
>
> ```
> $ sudo apt-get install lvm2
> ```
>
> 3- Load the necessary module(s):
>
> ```
> $ sudo modprobe dm-mod
> ```
>
> 4- Scan your system for LVM volumes and identify in the output the
>   volume group name that has your Fedora volume (mine proved to be
>   VolGroup00):
>
> ```
> $ sudo vgscan
> ```
>
> 5- Activate the volume:
>
> ```
> $ sudo vgchange -ay VolGroup00
> ```
>
> 6- Find the logical volume that has your Fedora root filesystem (mine
>   proved to be LogVol00):
>
> ```
> $ sudo lvs
> ```
>
> 7- Create a mount point for that volume:
>
> ```
> $ sudo mkdir /mnt/fcroot
> ```
>
> 8- Mount it:
>
> ```
> $ sudo mount /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /mnt/fcroot -o ro,user
> ```

Than whilst the partition is mounted, you should try to update grub configuration as explained in here:  [Ubuntu does not put Fedora into GRUB menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171947/ubuntu-does-not-put-fedora-into-grub-menu)

> sudo update-grub

Your Ubuntu should now see all partitions with bootloader settings and should add all OS'es into the grub.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Actually you're totally right, but I never find writing long answers useful while it is possible to explain the solution via shot links. However, it is true, I should include some parts of answer in here with reference.

Comment: Just add in any required code etc, you don't have to write an essay, just add the basics here. This site discriminates against link only answers, as, links can break or go missing and then your answer would go from being correct to worthless.